# Проблема с загрузкой linux после простоя

Tags: linux, grub

После простоя в месяц решил загрузить debian 11 со второго диска. Прошел grub, начал грузиться, но весь процесс остановился на

```
    /dev/sdb2: recovering journal
    /dev/sdb2: clean, ****/**** files, ****/**** block
```

И все, на этом все останавливается. Пробовал грузить предыдущую версию, recovery mode, но там никаких изменений, все заканчивается на

```
    Finished Flush Journal to Persistent Storage
```

Также не могу перейти в tty и залогиниться, там просто пустота и мигающий курсор.
Пробовал грузиться с livecd, там могу только получить доступ к содержимому диска и больше ничего.
Прошу помощи, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Наверное какие-то фатальные изменения в коде загрузчика на диске.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было создавать fstab в UUID. Проще всего теперь с загрузочной флешки примонтировать раздел с home, скопиравать все нужное и заново переустановить систему.